# Dropbox Setup, is it possible to sync files after I edit them?

Tags: dropbox

Ok so the question might be a bit vague but this is to all the  superusers of Dropbox.

I have an android phone, a Macbook, and a Windows desktop. I usually start my homework, coding, or themes on my computer and then I email or save the stuff on evernote and download it on my other device. Mostly between the mac and pc but I realized that I can use dropbox for seamless syncs to each device.

Let's say: I set up a folder called "theme-x" and I write some code for it on one computer and it syncs to my computer. Now if I edit the file on computer-2, will my files be replaced on all other devices? And is there a way to go back on the files? I haven't used any services like dropbox before so that's why I'm asking.

Comment: This is a valid SU question. **Please Note** Not every question containing the word web, is necessarily a migration option. Please think carefully before voting to migrate!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your changes will propagate across all connected devices. You can [see the history for any file for the past 30 days](https://www.dropbox.com/help/11). To keep a longer history, you can purchase the Pack-Rat feature.

[image: Restore using web interface]